# Relationship between Apple and Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, publish

I am mid-project, and I am using cocos2d. I was wondering today how Apple feel about the cocos2d framework, and how the submission process differs from that of a person who is not using cocos2d. Are there any special requirements that Apple has if you use cocos2d?

Comment: can't see any relationship at all

Comment: Can't see how this is relevant. I'm assuming that a concerned developer reads Apple's license agreements, or at the very least scans it for the search phrase "cocos2d". You won't find any mention of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, using cocos2d with distribution on the App Store is absolutely fine.
IF there is a bug or a crash or your app generally doesn't fit the guidelines then of course you're fine. But Apple is fine distributing any public API, **not** private API's, with a few exceptions. You are even allowed to sell apps that use the **beta** cocos2d.

There is no relationship, I don't think Apple generally cares about if your app uses Cocos2D or not. Just make sure it performs well.